# How to make a div center align in HTML

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to horizontally center a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

One simple way to make an object centered in HTML is using  `align='center'`, but it's not working for a div.

I tried:

```
style='text-align:center';
style='left:50%';
```

I even true a center tag

```
<center>
```

But I can't make my target div to be center.

Comment: Are you trying to center the div itself, or the text within the div?

Comment: i said in my question a div  not its text. thanks

Comment: Set a width for the `div`, then use `margin: 0 auto;`: http://jsfiddle.net/spikey/FLL5Z/

Comment: PLease note, the margin: 0 auto; solution only works when the top and bottom borders need to be 0. If they need to be changed, then the full version of this is, margin: 0 auto 0 auto; with the first "0" being top and second "0" being bottom. This can also be writen as margin-top: 0; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: auto.

Comment: easy way you can center anything is with flexbox as well. for x axis just set justify-content: center and for y axis you can set align-items: center;. to make a div completly in the middle center, use both! (for Parent element)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Center</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <div style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; background: #000; color: #fff;">This DIV is centered</div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Tested and worked in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera. I did not test IE6. The outer text-align is needed for IE. Other browsers (and IE9?) will work when you give the DIV margin (left and right) value of auto. Margin "0 auto" is a shorthand for margin "0 auto 0 auto" (top right bottom left).

Note: the text is also centered inside the inner DIV, if you want it to remain on the left side just specify text-align: left; for the inner DIV.

Edit: IE 6, 7, 8 and 9 running on the Standards Mode will work with margins set to auto.

Comment: i need to set with of my div percentage not fixed pixel , i think if if i set width to 95%  , it wouldnt be center

Comment: how do you know his div is in position relative or static ?

Comment: @Mac: this technique works just fine for a percentage width. However in general for auto-margin to work you must be in Standards Mode, for which you will need an appropriate `<!DOCTYPE` declaration. The parent-text-align-center workaround will work for Quirks Mode, but you absolutely don't want to be writing anything in Quirks Mode today.

Comment: hmm , it worked only in FF  not in IE ( any version ) pof hate this stupid IE

Comment: Try putting text-align: center; for IE.

Comment: u know text-align center text ,anyway i tried it but not worked

Comment: you need to wrap your div with another div, and set the outer div's style to be text-align for IE

Comment: Just writing a solution does not help people learn. You should try to teach rather then just get rid of people quickly.

Comment: Re: "The outer text-align is needed for IE." — For IE 5.5 and earlier! Support for auto margins was added in IE6 standards mode!

Comment: @thecoshman: Classes and books are for teaching. Stack Overflow is for answers.

Answer (score 16):

I think that the the `align="center"` aligns the content, so if you wanted to use that method, you would need to use it in a 'wraper' div - a div that just wraps the rest.

`text-align` is doing a similar sort of thing.

`left:50%` is ignored unless you set the div's position to be something like relative or absolute.

The generally accepted methods is to use the following properties

```
width:500px; // this can be what ever unit you want, you just have to define it
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

the margins being auto means they grow/shrink to match the browser window (or parent div)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Meo for poiting this out, if you wanted to you could save time and use the short hand propery for the margin.

```
margin:0 auto;
```

this defines the top and bottom as 0 (as it is zero it does not matter about lack of units) and the left and right get defined as 'auto' You can then, if you wan't override say  the top margin as you would with any other CSS rules.

Comment: you could use inline styles for margin.. margin: 0 auto;

Comment: problem is IE that can not show div exactly centered ; i tried margin-left-right : auto but not worked  on IE

Comment: @meo A fair point. Usually it would be best to take your advice as it helps reduce the file size, not much I know, but every little helps. Though for the guide, it helps explain the 'required' properties to get it to work.

Comment: @Mac Taylor - That might have something to do with the fact that there is no 'margin-left-right' property. You have to define the left, then the right or do it like meo suggests.

Comment: i just tried to type fast and i know there is no such a property ! 
uh

Comment: @Mac From experience, I can assure you that margin:auto works perfectly in IE6+. However... IE ignores it if you haven't correctly configured the doctype for the HTML page. It might also be a problem with how the container is defined.

Comment: just by adding "margin: auto" fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it depends if your div is in position: absolute / fixed or relative / static

for position: absolute & fixed

```html
<div style="position: absolute; /*or fixed*/;
width: 50%;
height: 300px;
left: 50%;
top:100px;
margin: 0 0 0 -25%">blblablbalba</div>
```

The trick here is to have a negative margin half the width of the object

for position: relative & static

```html
<div style="position: relative; /*or static*/;
width: 50%;
height: 300px;
margin: 0 auto">blblablbalba</div>
```

for both techniques, it is imperative to set the width.

Answer (score -1):

how about something along these lines

```
<style type="text/css">
  #container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; /* for IE */
  }

  #yourdiv {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
</style>

....

<div id="container">
  <div id="yourdiv">
    weee
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work on other browsers or in Standards Mode, since the auto margins would need to be on the same element as the width.

Comment: it works fine for me in modes other than Quirks, i don't understand the constant down-voting