# Centering fixed div inside a fixed div

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to center a fixed div inside another fixed div. I have tried many things but could not center it. How can i do this?

```css
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .60);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

.ques_preview_div {

    width: 60em;
    height: 30em;
    top: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #adadad;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">

<div class="ques_preview_div">

</div>

</div>
```

I could achieve what i needed by giving the position relative to ques_preview_div . But i need it to have position fixed.

Comment: look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691178/how-to-make-a-div-center-align-in-html

Comment: May I ask why you need .ques_prev_div to be fixed position it makes more sense to me to position it absolute in the fixed parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `right:0;` `left:0`  to `.ques_preview_div` , check with the snippet full screen

```css
.body {
    margin:0;
}
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .60);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

.ques_preview_div {

    width: 60em;
    height: 30em;
    top: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #adadad;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 4;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">

<div class="ques_preview_div">

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 property [`transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform#translate()) along with `top` and `left`.

```css
.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .60);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ques_preview_div {
  width: 60em;
  height: 30em;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #adadad;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="ques_preview_div">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pixels (px) instead of em on your width and hight of class ques_preview_div

```css
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .60);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

.ques_preview_div {

    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #adadad;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">

<div class="ques_preview_div">

</div>

</div>
```