# Why won't my div center in the screen using css?

Tags: html, css

I have one small question about css. I want the content .add-task-container and .task-container to show up in the middle of the screen but for some reason it is not working. I'm sure I have something wrong with my css but I just can't pinpoint which part. Would love it if someone can help me out and explain what needs fixing. Thank you!

```css
body{
    background: url(/todolist/img/DSC05921-6.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
    margin:0;
}

.content-container{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="add-task-container">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Task" id="input-task">
            <button id="add-task">ADD</button>
        </div>
        <div class="task-container">

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src=script.js></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It *is* centered horizontally. Do you want it also centered vertically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a div center align in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691178/how-to-make-a-div-center-align-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it centered horizontally *and* vertically, you could do this:

```
.content-container {
    display: grid;
    min-height: 100vh;
    place-content: center;
}
```

```css
.content-container {
    display: grid;
    min-height: 100vh;
    place-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
        <div class="add-task-container">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Task" id="input-task">
            <button id="add-task">ADD</button>
        </div>
        <div class="task-container">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying to my post. I'm sorry I forgot to mention it in the code. But basically I wanted the .add-task-container and .task-container to be inside this white box in the middle. In this case, should I add a padding to show this white box? I tried adding a background-color into the code added but it isn't showing the white box in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

In css

```
.content-container{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

Here,
`display: flex;` will align the child divs in same row, then `flex-direction: column;` will make the child divs in a column, then `justify-content: center;` will make child divs in vertically center and `align-items: center` will make the inner divs in horizontally centre.

---

if you remove the `flex-direction: column;` then `align-items: center` will make inner divs vertically center and `justify-content: center;` will make child divs horizontally center.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying to my post. I'm sorry I forgot to mention it in the code. But I wanted the .add-task-container and .task-container to be inside this white box. I tried adding a background-color into the code added but it isn't showing the white box in the middle.

Comment: I wrote the css that will center the both inner divs i.e. '.add-task-container' and '.task-container' those are inside '.content-container', but '.content-container' will cover the whole height. your background img isn't showing here, so if you want '.content-container' in center then  rewrite your question properly.

Comment: Also you can do the same thing I wrote in answer in 'body { ... }' or any parent class of '.content-container'.

Answer (score 0):

.content-container {

```
background: #FFFFFF;

width: 50%;

margin: auto;

text-align: center;

position: absolute;

top: 50%;

left: 50%;

transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

}

.add-task-container {

```
margin-top: 20px;
```

}

.task-container {

```
margin-top: 20px;
```

}